# Save Call on Java Mobile / Phone to mp3 or any Audio format / file

Tags: java-me, mobile, nokia, java

I want to Save Call on Java Mobile / Phone to mp3 or any Audio format / file .
How should I go ahead with.

I am quite well versed with Core Java.
I found apps supporting above mentioned functionality in symbian Phones only but NOT in Java phones whose MIDP version is 2.1 and above.

Thanks for your Idea ( obviously practical one's ! ) 
or
sharing some links relevant to this
or some sort of pseudo-code in java for this.

I want solution for Java Phones with MIDP 2.1 & above.Please don't recommend symbian or other such things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think nobody developed a call recorder in Java platform. All that you can do to record is to call divert to a land line which is connected to computer which can record calls.

Something for your reference (these can't provide you with Java phone call recording but can guide you , why it can't be with Java & S60 would be better(&only) option. )

[Java Voice Recorder ported from E398](http://www.motorolafans.com/forums/e6-applications/13370-app-java-voice-recorder-ported-from-e398.html)

[Need to develop a call recorder](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Discussion/showthread.php?213259-Need-to-develop-a-call-recorder)

and if change your mind from Java to Symbain then [here's a code which you can have a look a](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Automatic_Voice_Call_Recording)t.

Try Symbian!

Comment: Thanks for your answer but still i m sticking to java, for the same!

Answer (score 2):

If you are willing to record incoming call using j2me , than unfortunately it is not possible.

Comment: @user491518 , for security reason might be, try symbian directly

Comment: no, the requirement which i have, is only for Java phones MIDP 2.1

Comment: @Pratik, Sorry its not possible then

Comment: Well i know Symbian does it.Thanks for the answer but as olready specified in my question i m  strictly looking Java, due to some client specification which is not possible to change on any other platforms like symbiam,etc.plz stick to java when you answer

Comment: @Pratik :) I already specified it is not possible with java-me

Answer (score 1):

with Java ME API's in the currently available Nokia phones its not possible, But you can try with Symbian C++.

Comment: Ok Thanks.Then what can you recommend for Java Phone ? (Apart from Symbiam phones). Is there some way ?

Comment: Even java phone also its not possible. Java ME API's could not provide this for security purpose.

Answer (score 1):

j2me security will not allow to do this

you can do it with symbian.